# Sql Query To Create Attendance Report WIth Time Difference

Tags: sql-server-2008, report

I am working with a attendance report that should reflect the following output - The count of the employee attendance on time and late:

```
Department - OnTime - Late - Late_1_To_10_Mins
1 - 2 - 1 - 1
2 - 2 - 1 - 1
```

Right now, I've used the following query that got to work almost but repeating the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department,
CASE WHEN
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), InTime, 108)   = '10:00' THEN
(SELECT COUNT(PersonID) FROM Persons WHERE
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), InTime, 108)   = '10:00') ELSE 0 END AS OnTime,
CASE WHEN
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), InTime, 108)   > '10:00' THEN
(SELECT COUNT(PersonID) FROM Persons WHERE
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), InTime, 108)   > '10:00') ELSE 0 END AS Late 
FROM Persons
```

Output as follows:

```
Department - OnTime - Late
1 - 0 - 2
1 - 4 - 0
2 - 0 - 2
2 - 4 - 0
```

**Note:** I am not sure how to get the data between 1 to 10 minutes late and get to figure out it from the `InTime` column of the table. The above query at least should get me to the `OnTime` and `Late` data appropriately but seems like missing something. Below are the table structure and its sample data:

```
 CREATE TABLE [Persons] (
    [PersonID] [int] NULL ,
    [InTime] [datetime] NULL ,
    [OutTime] [datetime] NULL ,
    [Department] [int] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,  InTime,  OutTime,  Department)VALUES (1001, '2017-03-02 10:00:11.297', '2017-03-02 06:00:11.293', 1)
INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,  InTime,  OutTime,  Department)VALUES (1002, ' 2017-03-02 10:00:08.180', ' 2017-03-02 06:00:10.293', 1)
INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,  InTime,  OutTime,  Department)VALUES (1003, ' 2017-03-02 10:01:08.240', ' 2017-03-02 06:00:12.220', 1)
INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,  InTime,  OutTime,  Department)VALUES (1004, ' 2017-03-02 10:02:20.200', ' 2017-03-02 06:00:20.200', 2)
INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,  InTime,  OutTime,  Department)VALUES (1005, ' 2017-03-02 10:02:20.240', ' 2017-03-02 06:00:22.200', 2)
INSERT INTO Persons(PersonID,  InTime,  OutTime,  Department)VALUES (1006, ' 2017-03-02 10:04:20.100', ' 2017-03-02 06:00:20.320', 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given example data using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    department
  , OnTime = sum(case when convert(time,InTime) <  '10:01:00' then 1 else 0 end)
  , Late   = sum(case when convert(time,InTime) >= '10:01:00' then 1 else 0 end)
  , Late_1_To_10_Mins = sum(case 
        when convert(time,InTime) >= '10:01:00' 
         and convert(time,InTime) <  '10:11:00'
          then 1 else 0 end)
from persons
group by department
```

returns:

```
+------------+--------+------+--------------+
| department | OnTime | Late | Late_10_Mins |
+------------+--------+------+--------------+
|          1 |      2 |    1 |            1 |
|          2 |      0 |    3 |            3 |
+------------+--------+------+--------------+
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/NRQ26806

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim. Almost worked. Could you elaborate in brief why you have used this - `OnTime = sum(case when convert(time,InTime) <  '10:01:00' then 1 else 0 end)` I mean the **SUM** and 1 else 0 at the end?

Comment: That is letting us aggregation on values based on the conditions you described in your question. Alternatively you could use `coalesce(count(case when convert(time,InTime) < '10:01:00' then 1 end),0)`

Comment: I was actually unable to understand that section and now I knew. Thanks a lot and getting to know or more familiar with `Sql`. It worked perfectly.